# vertx getFormAttribute() returns null

Tags: vert.x

I'm trying to get form data from my html page on a post request but when I use the getFormAttribute() function, it returns null. Here is the code:

```
 Route postArticleRoute = router
                .post("/articlePosted")
                .handler(routingContext -> {
                    HttpServerResponse response = routingContext.response();
                    HttpServerRequest request = routingContext.request();
                    String title = request.getFormAttribute("title");
                    String auth = request.getFormAttribute("author");
                    String body = request.getFormAttribute("body");
                    System.out.println(title + auth + body);
                });
```

This code returns:  'nullnullnull'

I've double checked that these are the name attributes in the html form. Just in case, here is the html:

```
<form action="/articlePosted" method="post">
        <label>Title of Article</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="title" id="postArticle-title"><br><br>
        <label>Author</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="author" id="postArticle-auth"><br><br>
        <label>Image</label><br>
        <input type="file" name="file" id="postArticle-img"><br><br>
        <label>Body</label><br>
        <textarea style="width: 100%; height: 500px;" name="body" id="postArticle-body"></textarea><br><br>
        <input type="submit" value="Post">
    </form>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Since the form is sent with a POST request, you need to have the body loaded on the server side. Did you add a [`BodyHandler`](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_request_body_handling) to your route?

Comment: thanks, this fixed it. I had to add it.